# cartesian join in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

let's say i have the following data into table:

```
'1','nid'
'1','step.nid'
'2','step.nid'
'3','step.nid'
```

that mean that each nid can have multiple steps, in that case for nid=1 we have 3 steps.

How can I write the query in order to retrieve the following result:

```
'1','nid'
'1','step.nid'
'1','nid'
'2','step.nid'
'1','nid'
'3','step.nid'
```

so I need combined nid to each step

Comment: For rows 3 and 5 do you mean `'2','nid'` and `'3','nid'` respectively? If not, can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: no, so the idea is for each step i need to have 3 times same nid as I show in example same '1','nid' for each step

Comment: Do you have another column to explicitly sort these by? It will be hacky to make them sort the way you have them listed here.

Comment: Is it that you need a `'1','nid'` before any `'step.nid'`? I'm not sure I'm following how you get from the example table to the example result set.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that that's exactly what you expect, but hope it will helpful for you:

```
select *
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.str regexp t2.str and t1.id <> t2.id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select case o.type when 'nid' then n.column1 else s.column1 end output1,
       case o.type when 'nid' then n.column2 else s.column2 end output2
from yourTable n
cross join yourTable s
cross join (select 'nid' type union all select 'step') o
where n.column2='nid' and s.column2='step.nid'
order by n.column1, s.column1, o.type
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efe4a/4).